# MYSQL: Cant save 1000000 on a float field

Tags: mysql

I have a float column and I'm trying to save the value 1000000. It automatically turns it to 1e+06. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the value returned formatted as `1000000`, you can simply add integer zero to the column in the SELECT list.

```
SELECT mycol+0 AS mycol FROM mytable
```

MySQL is storing the value IEEE floating point format. (One bit for sign, a certain number of bits for the exponent, and a certain number of bits for the mantissa. This isn't really a MySQL thing, it's the standard representation for floating point values.)

As far as what's being returned, that's an issue with converting that value into string representation.

A floating point number has a large range of values. To represent the maximum value of a float (3.402823e+38) as a decimal value, that would require 38 decimal digits. The seven left most digits of the value are significant, but we'd need to add another 32 zeros/digits to indicate the position of the decimal point.

So, returning a string representation of scientific notation is a reasonable approach to returning a representation of the value.

Answer (score 1):

Those two things are equivalent:

```
  1e+06
= 1 * 10^6
= 1 * 1,000,000
= 1,000,000
```

It's called scientific notation (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)). mySQL uses it to display huge/tiny values, especially approximate values (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-numbers.html)).

Comment: MySQL uses it to *display* huge/tiny values. It uses IEEE floating point to store it, not anything like `1000000` or `1e+06`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOUBLE(8, 3) where 8 is the total no. of digits excluding the decimal point, and 3 is the no. of digits to follow the decimal.